# Prevent inline visualforce page from grabbing focus

Tags: inline-visualforce, iframe

We are using Eloqua's 'Profiler' page on our contact page.
Profiler is an inline VF page, that uses an apex iframe to retieve eloqua activities (emails) by contact email.

I've now implemented SSO (using sFDC as the IdP) to prevent my users from having to sign into Eloqua, but that has introduced an unwanted side effect:
IF the contact cant be found in eloqua (for example if there is no email address in SFDC) - once the iframe loads, it grabs the window focus as it presents a 'cant found contact' message.

I'd like to stop the iframe from doing that (grabbing the focus - the error is fine), but I cant seem to be able to do that. apex:iframe does not support an onfocus attribute, and adding a script to send the focus back to the top does not work (I think it fires BEFORE the iframe completed loading)

any ideas?

The VF page's code is:

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact"> 
    <apex:iframe src="https://login.eloqua.com/auth/saml2/autologin?LoginPrefix={!$Setup.EloquaSSO__c.Prefix__c}&Idp={!$Setup.EloquaSSO__c.Idp__c}&ReturnUrl=apps%2Fprofiler%3FemailAddress%3D{!contact.email}"/>
</apex:page>
```